# Label control color turn to white from black VB.NET WinForm

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am working with  VB.NET windows application my laptop is window 7 use for code program  when i build and install in my laptop  it's work correctly  but when i install  on user machine  which windows xp  control label and data grid view row color become white color in stead of black color as i was designed
what happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have used system colors to design the control. It will be different in different OS.Use Web or Custom colors instead.